# What is the meaning of PUP in remarks?

Tags: gm.general-mathematics

I see the remarks in Gowers’s The Princeton Companion to Mathematics. What is the meaning of the abbreviation ‘PUP’? Never seen before…

Comment: Princeton University Press.

Comment: Wikipedia disambiguation page [PUP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PUP) lists various meanings of this acronym - including [Princeton University Press](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princeton_University_Press).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thx, it should be Princeton University Press because the book was published by there.